# Swift base class depending on target (macros)

Tags: swift

I'd like to use macros to pick which class to inherit from.

You can use this syntax for say, import statements

```
#if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
#else
    import Cocoa
#endif
```

But it doesn't work for base classes (syntax errors)

```
#if os(iOS)
    class ImageView: UIImageView {
#else
    class ImageView: NSImageView {
#endif

    var rssi: Float? = nil {
        didSet {
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // do setup stuff
    }
}
```

I end up having two implementations of every method in the class which is hideous. Am I overlooking something, or missing out on a technique?

```
#if os(iOS)
    class ImageView: UIImageView {
        var rssi: Float? = nil {
            didSet {
                // do stuff
            }
        }

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // do setup stuff
        }
    }
#else
    class ImageView: NSImageView {
        var rssi: Float? = nil {
            didSet {
                // do stuff
            }
        }

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            // do setup stuff
        }
    }
#endif
```

Comment: I didn't know that there was a name for this "shimming". Duplicate link answers the question. Thank you.